# C++ string file redirection discrepancy?

Tags: c++, string, file, io

I am writing a program that takes input via standard input, and performs an action based on the input. However, I am getting an error on inputted txt files compared to my own input, and I am curious why.

```
std::string command;
std::getline(std::in, command); // first line is just "test"
if (command == "test")
{
    //works when I enter text manually through keyboard, but not from file
}

if (command.compare("test") == 1)
{
    //works reading the file
}
```

What gives? This is causing some logical errors in my program, but from what I have read == and .compare shouldn't be that different.

Anybody know how I can fix this possible encoding issue?

Comment: Show the content of your file.

Comment: what is the error that you are getting? can you edit the question to include the output of the error?

Comment: `string::compare` returns **zero** when strings are equal, so "works" is a lie.

Comment: Not a lie. The reason string::compare == 1 worked was because there was always an extra \r character.

Comment: That check didn't do what it was supposed to do, namely check for equality. It checked for inequality instead. If your file contained "whatever" or "zzzzz" or "teszt" the check would pass just the same.  Hence it didn't work. Hence "works" is a lie.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it. It turns out sometimes when reading from a file, the '\r' character is appended to the end. This caused my errors.

Hopefully this helps somebody else that gets stuck.

Comment: I'm guessing that you're running your program on a POSIX system (Linux, macOS, FreeBSD, ...) using an input file that was created on Windows.  If you were reading a file with Windows line-endings on a Windows system, the C++ runtime should recognize `"\r\n"` as a newline sequence automatically.

Comment: Yep, thats exactly the case. Thanks for the info!